# Mouse periodically locks up when using scroll wheel on mouse

Tags: windows-7, mouse, scroll-wheel

I have an end user whose computer locks up occasionally when using their mouse scroll wheel to scroll up and down on a website.

Has anybody ever seen this before? Any idea what it could be?

My initial thoughts are that it is likely related to the mouse driver but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few  simple tests would help eliminate  som ethings.  Besure you have latest driver.  If that fails, try a previous version.  If that fails, try a different mouse and driver if possible.

Will the mouse work without specific drivers from the manufacturer?  Try removing drivers, reboot and connect the mouse again.

Make and model of mouse would possibly help with a more precise answer.